# Python Enqueue and Dequeue Emulation Using a Subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, queue, subclass

As a relatively new python programmer, I have recently attempted to emulate enqueue and dequeue through the use of a class and subclass. Currently, my code read plus an attempt at an execution reads:

```
class queue:
    class node:
        def __init__(self, value, nextNode):
            self.value = value
            self.nextNode = nextNode

    def __init__(self):
        self.top = None
        self.last = None
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def enqueue(self, value):
        #This creates an extra node with "value" and inserts at the top
        newNode=queue.node(value,None)
        if self.size ==0:
            self.top=newNode
            self.last=self.top
            self.size+=1
        else:
            self.last.nextNode=newNode
            self.last=newNode
            self.size+=1      

    def dequeue(self):
        #This returns self.top.value and at the same time deletes the top 
         node.
        if self.size ==0:
            return "error: dequeue from an empty queue"
        elif self.size == 1:
            val=self.top.value
            nxt=self.top.nextNode
            self.top=None
            self.last=None
        else:
            val=self.top.value
            nxt=self.top.nextNode
            self.top=nxt
        return val

q = queue()
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)
q.enqueue(4)
x=q.dequeue()
output = []
while len(q)>0:
    x = q.dequeue()
    output.append(x)
print(output)
#This should show [2, 3, 4]
```

From what I can understand, my main issue is returning a value as currently I receive:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'

When I attempt to run. If someone could clarify where the issue lies, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decrement self.size when you dequeue stuff.  It's always 4 from running your program through pdb.

```
def dequeue(self):
    if self.size ==0:
        return "error: dequeue from an empty queue"
    elif self.size == 1:
        val=self.top.value
        nxt=self.top.nextNode
        self.top=None
        self.last=None
        self.size -= 1
    else:
        val=self.top.value
        next=self.top.nextNode
        self.top=next
        self.size
        self.size -= 1
    return val
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I missed that. I threw in a self.size-=1 in the dequeue statements and sure enough it works like a charm! Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: No problem at all Michael.  Nice job with everything else though.  I just dropped in two lines and it worked like a charm on my side.